# Is there a function for finding anti imaging correlation matrix in R? I can find it via excel but not in R

Tags: r, stat

Is there a function for finding anti imaging correlation matrix in R? I can find it via excel but not in R.
I tried searching for it but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to calculate the Kaiser-Meyer-Olkin (KMO) index? There is `KMO` function in the package `psych`.

If you review the source code by simply typing `psych::KMO`, you can see that the function actually calculates the anti imaging correlation matrix and returns it in the value `ImgCov`. See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/213060/what-is-the-difference-between-the-anti-image-covariance-and-the-anti-image-corr) about why it's called `ImgCov` and not `ImgCor`

Therefore, you can either calculate KMO index directly, or access the imaging correlation matrix.

```
library(psych)
KMO(Thurstone)$ImCov
             [,1]        [,2]         [,3]        [,4]         [,5]        [,6]        [,7]        [,8]         [,9]
 [1,]  0.26191905 -0.13247459 -0.098997433  0.01696386 -0.007869000 -0.01530553 -0.02683189 -0.02883750 -0.015467511
 [2,] -0.13247459  0.25042987 -0.093156627 -0.02997555 -0.013462396 -0.03933474 -0.01452050 -0.03244578  0.024857482
 [3,] -0.09899743 -0.09315663  0.325362301 -0.02885198  0.001412136 -0.01360381  0.01550812 -0.06027647 -0.009499454
 [4,]  0.01696386 -0.02997555 -0.028851979  0.44683097 -0.201926848 -0.14992727 -0.02064537  0.01507317 -0.051260798
 [5,] -0.00786900 -0.01346240  0.001412136 -0.20192685  0.479035204 -0.09880388 -0.03070355 -0.01220736 -0.070899784
 [6,] -0.01530553 -0.03933474 -0.013603811 -0.14992727 -0.098803879  0.57375353  0.02729260 -0.00322785 -0.014775752
 [7,] -0.02683189 -0.01452050  0.015508115 -0.02064537 -0.030703553  0.02729260  0.52259809 -0.16114288 -0.222865605
 [8,] -0.02883750 -0.03244578 -0.060276472  0.01507317 -0.012207363 -0.00322785 -0.16114288  0.54993095 -0.065094221
 [9,] -0.01546751  0.02485748 -0.009499454 -0.05126080 -0.070899784 -0.01477575 -0.22286561 -0.06509422  0.571067253
```

Comment: Thanks I did try KMO but didnt knew it gives that matrix as well.